# What Cognito Identity Pool does

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Please confirm or correct my understanding of what [Cognito Identity Pool Federation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/identity-pools.html) does.

1. Cognito Identity Pool does **mappings** between an **Identity Provider Temporary Token** and an **IAM Role of an AWS Account**. By which an Identity Provider account (e.g. Google account, Facebook account, etc) can use the AWS resources in the AWS account using a **Temporary AWS STS Token**.
2. Identity Providers provide Users and Authentication of the users. They are Google, Facebook, etc and Cognito Userpool is just another Identity Provider by AWS.
3. The **users** in the AWS Identity Provider (Userpool) has nothing to do with IAM account users nor groups.

[image]

Personally, I believe offering AWS's own Identity Provider service (Userpool) and Identity Provider Federation service (Identity Pool) under the same **AWS Cognito** is causing confusions.

Especially using the same terminology such as **User**, **Group**, **Federation** for different meanings depending on the contexts but both under "AWS Cognito".

The **user** and **group** in AWS Cognito Userpool has nothing to do with the AWS Account user and group. **Federation** in AWS Cognito Userpool is to pass the authentication process to the Identity Provider, whereas **Federation** in AWS Cognito Identity Pool is mapping Identity Provider Token (... or **user**) to an IAM Role.

Cognito Userpool AWS CLI is cognito-**idp** which can be confused with "IDentity Pool", but it is "IDentity Provider".

Cognito Identity Pool AWS CLI is cognito-**identity** but **identity** is managed by the Identity Providers, which AWS Cognito Userpool is.

## References

- [What Is Amazon Cognito?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-cognito.html)
- [What's the difference between Amazon Cognito user pools and identity pools?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-user-pools-identity-pools/)
- [AWS Cognito - User Pool Federation vs Identity Pool Federation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577606/aws-cognito-user-pool-federation-vs-identity-pool-federation)
- [Identity Pools Concepts (Federated Identities)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/concepts.html)
- [Adding User Pool Sign-in Through a Third Party](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-identity-federation.html) (Userpool Federation)

Comment: Yes, its confusing, especially since both user pools and identify pools allow you to login with facebook, google, etc.

Comment: Yes, it is very confusing, but I believe you understood it correctly. At least that is the same way that I understand it now and I used Cognito User Pool and Cognito Identity Pool for more than year using this mental model and it worked as expected. Not to mention that before that year I almost broke my head beating it in the table more than once...

Comment: I have not used Cognito for years now, and I just came across a new concept: `User Pool Client` which is used in CDK. I cannot find a confirmation for this, but I believe UserPoolClient is the same as identity pool. Anyone know if that's the case or if I'm way off here?