# React Native: What is returned by Auth.signIn()?

Tags: android, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

I am developing using react-native with Amazon AWS as back-end. I am also using `amplify` library.

For logging in, I am using the below call:

`const user = await Auth.signIn(...)`

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js#sign-in

https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/authclass.html#signin

My **related** questions:

1. I get a big JSON in the `user` variable. I believe it is the `AWS credential`?
2. The above `signIn()` call **DOES NOT** return a JWT token, it returns AWS credential. Is it? Also see the post:-
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/59327655/15943787

   Above post mentions:

> After successfully authenticating a user, Amazon Cognito issues JSON
> web tokens (JWT) that you can use to secure and authorize access to
> your own APIs, or exchange for AWS credentials

What is meant by above statement? What is `Auth.signIn()` doing? getting JWT token or credentials?

3. Does this returned credential get stored inside the mobile device? By default in android it is stored un-encrypted. Right?
4. Is it stored in sharedPreferences?

Comment: If this helped please upvote and/or mark as correct please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Auth.signIn()` returns a `CognitoUser` Object as defined in the [API Docs](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/authclass.html#signin).

Below is from AWS SDK for Android but the data in Javascript is the same, ([found here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-android/docs/reference/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/cognitoidentityprovider/CognitoUser.html)). The JWT Token in stored in the `CognitoUser.CognitoUserSession` attribute.

> Represents a single Cognito User.
> This class encapsulates all operations possible on a user and all tokens belonging to the user. The user tokens, as CognitoUserSession, are stored in SharedPreferences. Only the tokens belonging to the last successfully authenticated user are stored

So to answer your questions:

> 1. I get a big JSON in the user variable. I believe it is the AWS credential?

The user variable is a CognitoUser Object, which represents a single CognitoUser. to get the JWT token try `user.sessionId` or `user.tokenId`

> 2. The above signIn() call DOES NOT return a JWT token, it returns AWS credential. Is it? Also see the post:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59327655/15943787

It updates the CognitoUser with session and token JWT. Check the user object to find them, after Auth.signIn() the user Object would have updated if AWS issued tokens

> 3. Does this returned credential get stored inside the mobile device? By default in android it is stored un-encrypted. Right?

Its being stores in Shared Preferences. so yes it's on device and un-encrypted. But AWS manages updating the and changing the JWT as the user interacts with cognito automatically.

> 4. Is it stored in sharedPreferences?

Yes, it is stored in sharedPreferences

Comment: In my case Auth.signIn() ALWAYS returns undefined even though the sign in is successful.